# Вывод данных из бд через функцию

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

У меня есть отдельный файл с функциями functions.php в котором содержится следующая функция:

```
class func 
    public static function fillInfoAboutDeveloper($dbh){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM devpro.developers WHERE dev_status = 1";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;
    }
}
```

где $dbh -передача переменной с подключением к бд. 
И есть главная страница, где происходит отрисовка данных. 
На данный момент я пытаюсь это выводить вот так:

```
    <?php    
    func::fillInfoAboutDeveloper($dbh);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'Тут отрисовывается таблица';
    echo 'Какие-то данные'.$row["surname"];
    echo 'Опять какие-то данные'.$row["следующий столбец"];
    };
    ?>
```

Пока выводит сплошные ошибки. Я знаю, что неправильно описываю функцию и ее вывод. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
   class func 
        public static function fillInfoAboutDeveloper($dbh){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM devpro.developers WHERE dev_status = 1";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
```

Вторая часть

```
<?php    
  $developers = func::fillInfoAboutDeveloper($dbh);
  foreach($developers as $row) {
    echo 'Тут отрисовывается таблица';
    echo 'Какие-то данные'.$row["surname"];
    echo 'Опять какие-то данные'.$row["следующий столбец"];
  };
?>
```

**Через while:**

```
   class func 
        public static function fillInfoAboutDeveloper($dbh){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM devpro.developers WHERE dev_status = 1";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        }
    }
```

Вторая часть

```
<?php    
  $stmt = func::fillInfoAboutDeveloper($dbh);
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'Тут отрисовывается таблица';
    echo 'Какие-то данные'.$row["surname"];
    echo 'Опять какие-то данные'.$row["следующий столбец"];
  };
?>
```

Но здесь функция не возвращает полноценный результат запроса. А возвращает объект который еще в while обходиться, как на меня плохой вариант реализации

Comment: спасибо, работает. А вообще можно было сделать обход цикла через while, или тут только через foreach?

Comment: можно, но сначала нужно прочитать как строить структуру функционала. потому что можно напутать много

Comment: хорошо, еще раз спасибо.